# How to query a highscore list by most recent score in Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a MySql-table which assigns scores to players (Player1=>2000; Player2=>453; Player1372 =>43231) and saves the date with that information.

With every play there is a new Row added with a new (better or worse) score, so over time there are several different scores for each player. I now want to query the table to provide me with a list of the best players by score, but only considering the **most recent** game played by each player, so if Player1 has the highest score of all time, but his last game was realy bad, he is not to appear. Also, every player must only appear once in the list.

Input Example:

```
Player      | Score | Date
Player 1    |   50  | 2013.10.18 
Player 3    |   35  | 2013.10.18 
Player 2    |   60  | 2013.07.03 
Player 1    |   70  | 2013.08.02 
Player 1    |   20  | 2013.09.08 
Player 2    |   85  | 2012.10.22
```

Output: (Best on Top)

```
Player      | Score | Date
Player 2    |   60  | 2013.07.03 
Player 1    |   50  | 2013.10.18 
Player 3    |   35  | 2013.10.18
```

*Btw: In reality its not players, its all about URL scoring, but this is how I pictured the issue.*

Comment: Could you please post Input and output data?

Comment: Nothing that gave me a remotely promising result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a table that looks something like this

```
player | game_date |score
-------------------------
 1     | 10/12/2013| 700
 1     | 10/11/2013| 550
 2     | 10/12/2013| 100
 2     | 10/11/2013| 777
 3     | 10/10/2013| 654
 3     | 10/08/2013| 367
```

Then I would run this:

```
SELECT player, score
FROM tbl
JOIN (SELECT player, MAX(game_date) AS recent
      FROM tbl
      GROUP BY player) as tmp
  ON tmp.player = tbl.player
     AND tbl.game_date = tmp.recent
ORDER BY score DESC
```